# Two unnamed/unlined bizarre jquery errors

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm getting two consecutive bizarre jquery errors with no names, no line references and no references to anything outside of jquery. I haven't been able to locate the mysterious 'J' function of the first error in the jquery code either.

Both errors are loops

```
$.widget.destroy -> a.Widget._createWidget
```

and

```
f.fn.extend.triggerHandler -> f.fn.extend.remove
```

...followed by a few other lines before the error. I've copied them directly from Google's console, except I've cut off about 10 go-throughs of each loops that came below.

Using with Backbone.js, underscore.js and a few jquery plugins such as jquery-ui, jquery.chosen, jquery.spinner etc.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any suggestions much appreciated!!!

```
<error>
J
c.Event
c.Event
c.event.fix
c.event.handle
c.event.add.j.handle.o
f.fn.extend.remove
$.widget.destroy
a.Widget._createWidget
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
f.fn.extend.triggerHandler
a.cleanData
f.fn.extend.remove
$.widget.destroy
a.Widget._createWidget
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
f.fn.extend.triggerHandler
a.cleanData
f.fn.extend.remove
$.widget.destroy



<error>
c.event.add.j.handle.o
f.fn.extend.remove
$.widget.destroy
a.Widget._createWidget
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
f.fn.extend.triggerHandler
a.cleanData
f.fn.extend.remove
$.widget.destroy
a.Widget._createWidget
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i
f.event.trigger
f.fn.extend.triggerHandler
```

Comment: You are either using the plugins wrong or the plugins are buggy themselves

Comment: Something is causing them to get stuck in a recursive loop.

Comment: but wouldn't the widget references point rather to a jquery ui issue?

Comment: @Petrov, anything that uses jQuery UI's widget engine, actually. From the backtrace, it looks like some widget tries to recreate itself immediately when it gets destroyed, and then the new widget get destroyed right away, then tries to recreate itself, and so on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so the last few lines before the error is some kind of jquery ui emergency method for closing an infinite loop?

Comment: @Petrov, it looks more like an interpreter fail-safe to avoid a stack overflow.